# In Let’s go Pikachu can I move my mew to a new game?

Tags: pokemon-lets-go, pokemon-home

I want to make a new game on Let’s Go that only has Psychic Pokémon in my party. I already got my mew out from the pokeball plus though. Is it possible to put mew into Pokémon home, make a new game of Let’s Go on another Nintendo User account on my Switch and then move mew to that new game? I don’t want to buy another pokeball plus to get mew into the new game....

Comment: @Mathias711 I think this question is *slightly* different enough to not be considered a duplicate. This question is asking if they can move their Mew between new saves on different Nintendo accounts instead of the same Nintendo account

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you are able to move your Mew into your Pokemon Home storage and swap it between different accounts. This is mentioned on [Nintendo Support](https://en-americas-support.nintendo.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/48803#s3q4).

> When using Pokémon HOME, players can choose to deposit and withdraw Pokémon to and from any compatible save data on that Nintendo Switch system. That means that other players with Pokémon HOME can access Pokémon from your games on Nintendo Switch

[This Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BD9abkoPd3M) tutorial does a good job explaining how to do this. Below is a summary:

1. Open the Pokemon Home app
2. Choose the profile<sup>1</sup> you want to transfer the Mew *from*
3. Select "Let's Go" and move Mew into your Home Storage; save and exit
4. Return to the main page
5. Choose the profile you want to transfer the Mew *to*
6. Select "Let's Go" and move Mew into the Let's Go storage; save and exit

**Note**: If your secondary account does not have a premium subscription, you can only access the first box within Pokemon Home. Assuming your primary account has a premium subscription and you place Mew into a box that's not the first one, you will not be able to access it.

---

<sup>1</sup> Image taken from Youtube video on how to switch profiles 
[image: Switching profiles]

Comment: Wait, so I need a premium account in Pokémon home to transfer mews?

Comment: @Multavit You don’t need premium to transfer Mew, just to use additional boxes.

Comment: Alright, so essentially I choose first profile, move mew over, select second profile and send mew over.